# NEON - Store 128bit values

Tags: neon

I am newbie to Neon assembly. I am trying to save 128bit values in "q" registers to memory using (vst3.16). I am getting only 64bit "d" saved.

Code is:

```
 __asm__ __volatile__
(
    "vld1.u16   {q0}, [%[bay0]]             \n\t"
    "vld1.u16   {q1}, [%[bay1]]             \n\t"
    "vld1.u16   {q2}, [%[bay2]]             \n\t"

    "vst3.16   {d0,d2,d4}, [%[dst]:64]          \n\t"

    : [bay0]"+r"(bay0), [bay1]"+r"(bay1), [bay2]"+r"(bay2), [dst]"+r"(dst)
);
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You're using an instruction that operates on d registers, specifying d registers as arguments, and it's saving d registers? Sounds fine to me ;) I suspect any confusion here is down to your toolchain lying to you about the loads - [`VLDn` also only operates on d registers](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473l/dom1361289956432.html), but your assembler is just allowing `{q0}` as a shorthand for `{d0, d1}` - try compiling this then running it through a disassembler to compare.

Comment: Yes,  noticed that compilers accepts {q0} as {d0, d1}. Now, is there a neon instruction equivalent to the intrinsic vst3q_u16 which store a full q at a time?

Comment: [Sure there is  (an equivalent)](https://goo.gl/TYAULE) - after all, that intrinsic has to compile to _something_. It's just not "an" instruction...

Comment: Thanks a lot! btw, what does "!" mean at the end of some instructions?

Comment: Update base pointer by size of the store.

Comment: The `!` syntax in general means "write back an updated value to the base register"; the exact behaviour depends on the specific instruction. It's all covered in the instruction docs, although ARM's various [programmer's guides](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.den0018a/index.html) might be worth a look for a gentler introduction (note some of them require (free) registration to access).